# How to display image from an URL and display it on tap of a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to know how to display image from URL (which is in xml file) on tap of button.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a view
[superView addSubview:myButton];
```

And function after tapping button

```
-(void)buttonClicked{
    //urlString should be your image url which you want to access
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString ];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
}
```

Use image where you want to display.........

Answer (score 2):

```
   UIImage *pImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];;
  [imageView setImage:pImage];
```